# Creating a hotmail account from C#

Tags: c#, account, hotmail

Does anybody know how I would go about creating a new hotmail account from C# ?
Screenscraping and POSTing ? or is there a simpler way ?

Comment: Y'know, if I were cynical, I'd wonder why you want to do that?

Comment: Because I'm writing an MSN bot for fun.
What I want is that when people want to play with the bot, they don't have to register a hotmail-account themselves for it but it does that automaticly.

Comment: To elaborate, something like an ELIZA bot using DotMSN  ( http://www.xihsolutions.net/dotmsn/ )

Comment: If you really want to do that, POSTing is probably the only way. If Microsoft wanted you to be able to automatically create accounts, they would probably provide an API to do it.

Comment: Doesn't the Hotmail register process involve a CAPTCHA?

Comment: Yeah, screen-scraping and POSTing is the way to go...but could you share your library for getting around the CAPTCHA, I've got a spamming service to start? ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'll take a wild guess here and say that bot-created accounts might be against their ToS.

You might be better off asking the users to create an account for themselves, or helping out a little bit by sending them to the register page or display it in a browser component inside the application, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you will be able to do it as you will required to solve a Captcha.

Answer (score 1):

Although I seriously doubt Microsoft has provided this in the Live API, it never hurts to take a look, I guess:

[Live Services SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264574.aspx)

[Get Started With Live Services](http://dev.live.com/)